# Calling specific method inside a WSDL Web Service (SOAP) using Ionic v3/v4

Tags: api, web-services, ionic-framework, soap, wsdl

I have a WSDL Web Service URL, and that URL contains multiple functions I must call them in order to get response in Ionic v3/v4. How can I call these functions?

Currently I managed only to retrieve the whole XML date into my application using this code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import xml2js from 'xml2js';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  headers: any;
  xmlItems: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 

  }

  checkAPI()
  {

    this.http.get('https://MyWebService/svc/AllServices.svc?wsdl', { responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data => {
    this.xmlItems = data;
    console.log("data:"+data);
    xml2js.parseString(this.xmlItems, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
}
```

Inside this WSDL Web Service I have multiple function for example (GetAllVehicles), but I don't know to how to retrieve the data.

Comment: Did you try with `https://MyWebService/svc/AllServices.svc/GetAllVehicles`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(
  url,
  {
    headers : new HttpHeaders(
      {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
        'SOAPAction': ''
      }
    )
      ,Accept: 'text/xml;charset=utf-8'
      ,responseType: 'text'
  });
```

Try to call SOAP API with SOAPUI or Postman to be sure the headers you must to pass to get SOAP call running.